# How to make not selected fragments appear a little smaller than the currently selected fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using a FragmentPagerAdapter to create carousel between 3 fragments. I've achieved it, but I'd like to make the adjacent fragment appear a little smaller, like in the following:

[image: gif]

My code:

```
    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    vpPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    vpPager.setPadding(60,0,60,0);
    vpPager.setPageMargin(5);


    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection-android check this cool library out if you can use 3rd party lib

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply...I'd rather not use a 3rd party lib in this case if its possible and not that much time consuming

Comment: No its not sometimes sof have negative people don't worry about it and check the github link I shared u can refer the code and make ur feature work. Instead of using 3rd party library u can refer there code and get how to do it.